# Sending emails in Alexa Skill Fact through nodemailer

Tags: node.js, json, alexa-skills-kit, package.json

This is my first post so apologies if my question doesn't make sense. I am new to node.js and Alexa skill fact. I am working on an Alexa skill Fact that has the capabilities of sending an email to a ticketing system. I want to do this through NodeJS Nodemailer. I believe that I have to have nodemailer installed on the developer console for this to work. I don't know how to download and use Nodemailer on Alexa developer console. I am using the Alexa Hosted (Beta) service and testing on the Alexa simulator if that changes anything.

I have looked into IFTTT, but that is not what I want, as the sender's email will change with whoever uses this skill and with a different message, and I don't believe that is capable with IFTTT. I have looked into creating the email and sending the email in the js file itself, and that seems to be my best bet.

I want to add this code to my index.js file

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

function emailsender(){
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        user: 'email@email.com',
        pass: 'password'
      }
    });

    var mailOptions = {
      from: 'email@email.com',
      to: 'email.email.com',
      subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
      text: 'That was easy!'
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      }
    });
    return "success";
}
```

so I believe I need to have the Nodemailer package in my package.json file as well, code taken from  https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/master/package.json

```
{
    "name": "nodemailer",
    "version": "6.1.0",
    "description": "Easy as cake e-mail sending from your Node.js applications",
    "main": "lib/nodemailer.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "grunt"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer.git"
    }, 
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

but I cannot add this to my already existing package.json file because name and version etc are all unique keys that cannot be duplicated.

My main three questions are:

1. Can I use Nodemailer in Alexa?
2. How do I download Nodemailer into the Alexa developer console?
3. Do I need to insert the Nodemailer package.json into my existing package.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Code" menu, in the Alexa developer console (hosted skill), add "nodemailer" to the dependencies (in package.json).

```
"dependencies": {
  "nodemailer": "^6.1.0"
}
```

Then add your code to index.js and let's see what happens.

You have to be familiar with a few things: Amazon lambda and basic node programming.